# A program that takes two lists, and prints 1 list with the values common within them

Tags: python

I have tried this, but I don't know what's wrong with my code, it prints the correct values, however, when I append the values it prints None, as well as, it keeps saying there is error in the line `if L1[q]==L2[q]:`

```
a= [3,1,4,5]
b= [3,4,5]
def intersect(L1,L2):
    q=0
    w=0
    li=[]
    if len(L1)>len(L2):
        while q<len(L1):
            for i in L1:
                if L1[q]==L2[q]:
                    print li.append(L1[q])     
                    q+=1
                else:
                    L1.remove(L1[q])
    if len(L2)>len(L1):
        while w<len(L2):
            for i in L2:
                if L2[w]==L1[w]:
                    print li.append(L2[q])
                    q+=1
                else:
                    L2.remove(L2[q])
intersect(a,b)
```

Comment: certainly because both the list are not of same length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sets to get the intersection of two lists like:

**Code:**

```
def intersect(L1, L2):
    print(list(set(L1) & set(L2)))
```

**Test Code:**

```
a = [3, 1, 4, 5]
b = [3, 4, 5, 6]

intersect(a, b)
```

**Results:**

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a= [3,1,4,5]
b= [3,4,5]
print(list(set(a)&set(b))) #<===
```

**RESULT**

[3,4,5]

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!